# duplicate column names in query

Tags: mysql, sql

I don't think it's possible but I thought I would ask anyways.

I have a MySql 5.+ query as such...

```
SELECT p.*, u.* FROM princess p JOIN unicorn u ON p.id = u.princess_id
```

It's kind enough to return me all of the princesses and unicorns ;).  The problem is that the returned result set may contain duplicate column names (not good).  If both tables have a column named `name` how can I differentiate it without explicitly coding the alias like `p.name as 'princess_name'` and `u.name as 'unicorn_name'`?

Also, I can't use the column index so if there isn't a better way I'll just hand code all the aliases myself.

Comment: "without explicitly coding the alias" - What's wrong with aliases? What's the use case behind not using aliases in the query, especially when the column names are identical?

Comment: If there are duplicate columns, then some MySQL libraries add table alias to the column name automatically. But it's always recommended to specify aliases explicitly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SELECT *` is bad idea for several reasons, one of which you've just found. Use an explicit column list and create your own aliases.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to hand code all the aliases yourself. ;) Anyway, getting rid of those `*` won't be a bad thing.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible, and also, try to avoid using the `*` in SQL. 
It is a bad habit. Writting all your fields is better for readibility AND PERFORMANCE, don't forget that!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to hand code the aliases.
And this is good. It is always a good idea to explicitly mention all the column names.

Answer (score 0):

If you fetch the rows as an array, you could rely on the order of the data. If you fetch them as a map/dictionary...you're probably out of luck. Really though, aliasing is a much better idea.

PS. Star selects are bad form.

Answer (score 0):

String query1="SHOW COLUMNS FROM uploadfile LIKE '"+label+"'";
                              ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(query1);

```
                          while(rs.next())
                          {
                         //   int rs = 0;

                              pw.println("<script>alert(' throw new DuplicateName()')</script>"); 

                              pw.write("Error in file insertion"+rs);
                              response.sendRedirect("AddAttribute.jsp?status='Error'");

                          }

                              String query ="ALTER TABLE uploadfile ADD  "+label+" varchar (10)";
                               System.out.println("welcome in java ");

                              int rs1=st.executeUpdate(query);


                               response.sendRedirect("afterlabel_updatefile.jsp?status='success'");

                           //  response.sendRedirect("AdminHome.jsp");
```